# Flash, getURL works from time to time

Tags: flash, swfobject, geturl

I'm not a flasher, but i did a menu for site on flash
i have about 10 buttons working like hyperlink using getURL.
So, problem is:
it works perfectly on my netbook (Win XP - Mozilla/Chrome/IE - last flash player)
it works perfectly on my wife's laptop (Vista - Mozilla/chrome/IE - last flash player)
But it does not work at all on my employer's computers (XP/Vista - Mozilla/Chrome - last flash player)
I'm using swfobject (i'm not sure what version is, but i think it's 2.x)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your target is set to _blank but the image on your employer's computer is set to block popups? Therefore it looks like it's not working since it can't open a new window to display the content?

Comment: no, i didn't specified second parameter, so on my computer it works as _self, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding allowscriptaccess = "always":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};

params.allowscriptaccess = "always"; 
swfobject.embedSWF(//etc...
```